# Subtle bug in generating comment links

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks

I've posted a wikipedia link as a comment to this post:

[Are there common methods for hashing an input file to a fixed set of values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962101/are-there-common-methods-for-hashing-an-input-file-to-a-fixed-set-of-values)

Apparently the length of the link has fallen on the threshold that SO uses to truncate comments and add ellipsis and an off-by-one error has caused it to add an unnecessary trailing slash to the link text.

(I've added the comment to this post and the behavior is reproducible)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function

Comment: http://te.wikipedia.org/wikiPerfe/ct_hash_function

Comment: http://te.wikipedia.org/wikiPerfect_hash_function

Comment: Hmm.. doesn't seem to be a problem for my test comment. The Url is a dummy one, yea?

Comment: @o.k.w: it's not about the url, it's about the length of the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed now!

Thanks!